# In Python 3, how to suppress method parameters in the output of "help"?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a class, `Node`, in Python 3. Calling `help(Node)` in IDLE yields messages of the type

```
   makeLeft(self, d=None)
       N.makeLeft([d]) -> None

       Create empty node as left child of N. If d is provided, it is
       set as the left child's data.
```

I want to suppress parameter names in this output, e.g. `help(str)` yields

```
   strip(...)
       S.strip([chars]) -> str

       Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
       whitespace removed.
       If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

How can I suppress parameters in the help for my class?

Comment: Why do you want to make your `help` less helpful?

Comment: I do not think `help` becomes less helpful. It becomes less confusing by suppressing the self parameter and default values. The docstring provides sufficient explanation. Python seems to follow the same methodology, as illustrated by the output of `help(str)`.

Comment: That's because `str` is implemented in C, so can't be introspected. Why would `self` be confusing, or the existence or default value of the second argument?

Comment: I want to talk about trees in a class where we have not yet done OOP or default parameters. I wrote the Node class for that purpose. I fear the discussion will now veer into what self is, and the assignment in the parameter list. Had I known that these will be appearing in the help, I would have planned it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think `help(str)` suppresses it because it allows a variable number of inputs.

Comment: I thought so, too, but that seems not to be the case. Try `help(str.zfill)`. Calling `str.zfill` incorrectly yields `TypeError: zfill() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`.